How can I integrate MLKit library without using cocoapods?
I want to integrate MLKit library without using cocoapods. Is there a way to somehow copy/paste or drag and drop method to use this?
Or maybe there is another solution, maybe I can fetch library to another project and then somehow copy frameworks/libraries to project without cocoapod?
Thank for any help.

On: https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/migration/ios "The ML Kit library is only provided as cocoapods. You can't mix frameworks and cocoapods, so in order to use this library you need to first migrate to use cocoapods." You should be able do it manually, but you'll need to integrate also all the dependencies in https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/b/e/b/GoogleMLKit/3.2.0/GoogleMLKit.podspec.json (the link on the source should get you the lib), but you should also put the flags/headerpaths if needed, etc. And if there is an update, do it all again...

@Larme Huh, that's a bit odd isn't it? I totally expected that Google would provide a SPM package.

They did for GoogleMaps (and related one) since end of 2023 I think, but it doesn't seem to be the case yet on MLKit.
